# Find and replace characters between XML tags

Tags: xml, perl

I have an XML file that is not bound by lines. It has the tags `<tag1>` and `</tag1>` that has some trashed variables from the code that generated it (I am not able to correct that right now). I would like to be able to change the characters within these tags to correct them. The characters are sometimes special.

I have this Perl one-liner to show me the contents between the tags, but now I want to be able to replace in the file what it has found.

```
perl -0777 -ne 'while (/(?<=perform_cnt).*?(?=\<\/perform_cnt)/s) {print $& . "\n";      s/perform_cnt.*?\<\/perform_cnt//s}' output_error.txt
```

Here's an example of the XML. Notice the junk chars in-between the tags `perform_cnt`.

```
<text1>120105728</text1><perform_cnt>ÈPm=</perform_cnt>
<text1>120106394</text1><perform_cnt>†AQ;4K\_Ô23{YYÔ@Nx</perform_cnt>
```

I need to replace these with like a 0.

Comment: Please update your question with sample of the input file that you need to process.

Comment: [Have you tried using an XML parser instead?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/725418)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It is a bad practice to use regex for xml parsing

Anyway - the **code** is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $tag = 'perform_cnt';

open my $fh, '<file.txt' or die $!;
foreach (<$fh>) {
  s/(<$tag>)(.*?)(<\/$tag>)/$1$3/g;
  print "$_";
}
close $fh;
```

And **output** is:

```
<text1>120105728</text1><perform_cnt></perform_cnt>
<text1>120106394</text1><perform_cnt></perform_cnt>
```

Comment: If you wanna eliminate `<perform_cnt></perform_cnt>` from output, then replace in code `/$1$3/` with `//`.

Comment: also, output for `print "$_"` is not the best. use `print;`

Comment: @loldop - If you are looking for short code, then maybe. Otherwise I don't see a reason for that. Short code then can look like `s/(<$tag>)(.*?)(<\/$tag>)/$1$3/g && print for <$fh>;` replacing the entire `foreach` loop.

Comment: it's the same. if you want, use `print; print "\n"; ` OR `print "$_\n";` but ordinary i use `say` function `say{ return (@_,"\n");}`

Comment: @loldop - I know what is that, but it is just not standard use and actually `say` is from Perl 5.10+ I believe, so not each Perl got it.

Comment: you use : `s///` instead `$_=~s///` - so do i with `print`. 
also use `for` instead `foreach`

Comment: @loldop - I never said you are wrong, I am just using the code as I believe it standard use. Yes, `s///` is pretty standard to be used without `$_=~`. Anyway - you are welcome to post your own answer and I will be glad to upvote it if it compiles and works - that's important as the style of source code is very personal :)

Comment: yeah, style is very personal, while you are coding on your own :\ but it is another thread. your answer is full for this question :)

Comment: Well, it works accidentally. At some point, you're going to cause problems by taking these shortcuts, especially when it's so easy not to.

Answer (score 8):

I love [XML::Twig](https://www.metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig) for these sorts of things. It takes a little getting used to, but once you understand the design (and a little about DOM processing), many things become extremely easy:

```
use XML::Twig;

my $xml = <<'HERE';
<root>
<text1>120105728</text1><perform_cnt>ÈPm=</perform_cnt>
<text1>120106394</text1><perform_cnt>†AQ;4K\_Ô23{YYÔ@Nx</perform_cnt>
</root>
HERE

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(   
    twig_handlers => { 
        perform_cnt   => sub { 
            say "Text is " => $_->text;  # get the current text

            $_->set_text( 'Buster' );    # set the new text
            },
      },
    pretty_print => 'indented',
    );

$twig->parse( $xml );
$twig->flush;
```

With indented pretty printing, I get:

```
<root>
  <text1>120105728</text1>
  <perform_cnt>Buster</perform_cnt>
  <text1>120106394</text1>
  <perform_cnt>Buster</perform_cnt>
</root>
```